How to check whether a triangulated subcategory is admissible?
Let $\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ be a full triangulated subcategory. Recall, $\mathcal{T}'$ is called $\textit{right admissible}$ if the inclusion $\mathcal{T}' \hookrightarrow \mathcal{T}$ admits a $\textit{right adjoint}$ $\pi : \mathcal{T} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}'$.
A left admissible subcategory is defined dually, and we call a subcategory $\textit{admissible}$ if it is both left and right admissible.
Equivalently, $\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is right admissible if and only if for every $A \in \mathcal{T}$, there exists a distinguished triangle
$B \rightarrow A \rightarrow C \rightarrow B[1]$
with $B \in \mathcal{T}'$ and $C \in \mathcal{T}'^{\perp}$, where $\mathcal{T}'^{\perp}$ denotes the $\textit{right orthogonal complement}$.
A similar equivalent condition exists for left admissible subcategories.
Admissible categories come up in many important contexts, for example, in semi-orthogonal decompositions.
My question is this: are there any examples where one can 'easily see' whether a given triangulated subcategory is admissible (or left admissible or right admissible) without having to check/prove the above abstract conditions?
For example, if $\mathcal{T} = D^{b}(X)$ is the bounded derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a scheme $X$, are there any conditions on $X$ that allows one to 'see' whether a triangulated subcategory is admissible or not?
I put 'easily see' and 'see' in quotes because I do not expect any non-trivial answer to make the above super easy, but the above two conditions, at least to me, seem quite abstract to check in most cases.
I am sure this is not a new question, and answers are available in the literature, but I am not found a source where such examples are 'collected'. Indeed, it would be useful to have such a collection to develop an intuition for these things.
Any help/pointing to references would be much appreciated.

The answer is much easier for unbounded derived categories of Grothendieck categories. In this case the category satisfies Brown representability, so full subcategories have left/right adjoint to the embedding functor iff they are closed under direct products/sums and direct summons.

The key word to ggogle is: "Bousfield localization". In the context of triangulated categories with small coproducts, Neemans book Triangulated Categories (Princeton Univ. Press) is all about this. If you are happy with stable $\infty$-categories, this is what the notion of presentable $\infty$-category is there to do for you.

If you want this kind of property for triangulated categories like the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on a noetherian scheme, Neeman's notion of approximable triangulated category gives rather general answers; see arXiv:1806.06995 for a survey. Similar ideas may be found in this very nice paper of Ben-Zvi, Nadler and Preygel: arXiv:1312.7164

DenisT and D.-C.Cisinski Thank you for your comments. This is much appreciated :)

One very useful example is the following: assume $\mathcal{T} = \mathrm{D}^b(\mathrm{coh}(X))$, and $\mathcal{T}' = \mathrm{D}^b(\mathrm{coh}(X'))$, where $X$ and $X'$ are smooth projective varieties. Then any fully faithful embedding $\mathcal{T}' \hookrightarrow \mathcal{T}$ is admissible, because in the geometric case any fully faithful functor
$$
\mathrm{D}^b(\mathrm{coh}(X')) \hookrightarrow
\mathrm{D}^b(\mathrm{coh}(X))
$$
is a Fourier--Mukai functor by Orlov's representability theorem, and any Fourier--Mukai functor between smooth projective varieties has both left and right adjoints.

Suggested edit for clarity: "Then the image of every fully faithful functor $\mathcal{T}'\to \mathcal{T}$ is admissible." Otherwise there is no relationship between $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$. Or/similarly "in the geometric case the fully faithful functor" replace "the" with "every."

@PiotrAchinger: In the original question $\mathcal{T}'$ was assumed to be a subcategory of $\mathcal{T}$ (hence a fully faithful functor is fixed), so this is the assumption I am working with.

@Sasha: Just for the sake of clarity, can you please specify the relationship between $X$ and $X'$?

@SunnySood You do not need any additional structure. You only need both the ambient category, and the full subcategory to be (abstractly) equivalent to $D^b$ of smooth protective variety; this is a property of separate categories, which is independent from choice of embedding.

@SunnySood: OK, I edited my answer following the suggestion of Piotr to make it more clear. So, indeed, as Denis explained the argument works for any fully faithful functor.

This is clearer now. Thank you very much for your time and thoughts.
